# Bing Translation Api access via SOAP interface from Ruby

Tags: ruby, web-services, soap, bing-api, savon

I'm trying to use Bing Translator SOAP API (due to in HTTP API I'm getting 414 "Request too long" for not so big requests due to UTF-8 serialization).

So, I'm playing with [bing_translator gem source](https://github.com/CodeBlock/bing_translator-gem) trying to switch it from HTTP inerface to SOAP one using Savon SOAP toolkit.

My workflow as follows ([access token getting function](https://github.com/CodeBlock/bing_translator-gem/blob/bcf80ca47628f50d4714e1802d5602b5018bc6ed/lib/bing_translator.rb#L143) not shown):

```
WSDL_URI = 'http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/soap.svc?wsdl'

get_access_token
client = Savon.client(wsdl: WSDL_URI, headers: {'Authorization' => "Bearer #{@access_token['access_token']}"})

params = {
  'from'        => 'ru',
  'to'          => 'en',
  'text'        => 'Это текст для перевода',
  'category'    => 'general',
  'contentType' => 'text/plain'
}

result = client.call(:translate, message: params)
```

Then SOAP request executes:

```
SOAP request: http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/soap.svc

Authorization: Bearer http%3a%2f%2fschemas.xmlsoap.org%2fws%2f2005%2f05%2fidentity%2fclaims%2fnameidentifier=invest_amurobl_ru&http%3a%2f%2fschemas.microsoft.com%2faccesscontrolservice%2f2010%2f07%2fclaims%2fidentityprovider=https%3a%2f%2fdatamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net%2f&Audience=http%3a%2f%2fapi.microsofttranslator.com&ExpiresOn=1381128612&Issuer=https%3a%2f%2fdatamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net%2f&HMACSHA256=Mw41PMMgw2n6ZVaGRXtwfR0vwMJUyIMltIyd9pa9MqA%3d
SOAPAction: "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/LanguageService/Translate"
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 454

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:wsdl="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<env:Body>
<wsdl:Translate>
<to>en</to>
<text>Это текст для перевода</text>
<category>general</category>
<contentType>text/html</contentType>
<from>ru</from>
</wsdl:Translate>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

And I'm getting error 500: `Unhandled Service Exception`

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
<s:Fault>
<faultcode>s:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring xml:lang="en-US">Unhandled Service Exception</faultstring>
<detail>
<int xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">1</int>
</detail>
</s:Fault>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

What's may be wrong? Can anyone who already using Bing Translator SOAP API to diff my soap-messages with yourself? Any advices to how to troubleshoot this.

Thanks for attention.

**EDIT:**

I've checked API with SoapUI, as @SteffenRoller advices and it works. Here is XML generated by SoapUI (values are inserted by hand):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v2="http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v2:Translate>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <v2:text>Текст, который я хочу перевести</v2:text>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <v2:from>ru</v2:from>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <v2:to>en</v2:to>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <v2:contentType>text/plain</v2:contentType>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <v2:category>general</v2:category>
      </v2:Translate>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

As you can see the only difference is that all the tags inside a `<Body>` are in the `v2` namespace. In the XML, generated by Savon this namespace isn't present at all.

So, now question is: **How to instruct Savon to use correct namespace for tags inside the message body?**

Although, I think, this is a Savon bug, I'll file it to developers, as SoapUI have generated correct XML by the same WSDL, and Savon doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried with SoapUI? Did it work? Make it work with SoapUI first. Implement it in the 2nd step in Ruby/Savon.

Comment: @SteffenRoller, thanks for advice. It works in SoapUI, but XML is different, see updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. This is a known bug: [Savon issue #340](https://github.com/savonrb/savon/issues/340). It's related to composite WSDL files and won't bi fixed in current major release :-(

So, in our case we need to tell Savon, what is our namespace is, what is it's name (just to align it with WSDL) and prepend each tag's name with this namespace.

The correct code looks like this:

```
require 'savon'

access_token = "http%3a%2f%2fschemas.xmlsoap.org%2fws...CA9TEs%3d"

client = Savon.client(
  wsdl: 'http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/soap.svc?wsdl',
  namespace: 'http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2',
  namespace_identifier: :v2,
  headers: {'Authorization' => "Bearer #{access_token}"},
)

params = {
  'v2:text'        => 'Это текст для перевода',
  'v2:from'        => 'ru',
  'v2:to'          => 'en',
  'v2:contentType' => 'text/plain',
  'v2:category'    => 'general',
}

result = client.call(:translate, message: params)

puts result.body[:translate_response][:translate_result]
```

Any advices and corrections are welcome. Thanks.